# Unable to copy pub key with ssh-copy-id (ERROR: No such file)

Tags: linux, ssh, openssh

I'm trying to use the ssh-copy-id command on my local host to copy a pub file to the remote host [using these instructions](https://www.vultr.com/docs/how-to-add-and-delete-ssh-keys).

```
user@local-host:~$ ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa_Tran.pub username@ipAddress
```

I can confirm I have the pub file in my .ssh folder [(link to screeshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQk7B.png)
Unfortunately, I'm getting an error when I try to run the command:

```
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: ERROR: failed to open ID file '/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa_Tran': No such file
    (to install the contents of '/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa_Tran.pub' anyway, look at the -f option)
```

I checked the meaning of [the -f option](https://man.archlinux.org/man/core/openssh/ssh-copy-id.1.en) but I don't know if I should be using that. Why can't it just find the file that I have in my .ssh directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look closely, it's trying to find a *different* file – it's trying to find the **private key** file that is usually adjacent to the .pub file, which would be used to check whether the key is already present.

You don't have the private key, only the public key, so you have no other choice but to skip this check using the `-f` option.

Answer (score 0):

If you've created the keypair, you don't specify the public key `.pub` with `ssh-copy-id`.

```
pg@TREX:~$ ls .ssh
authorized_keys  id_rsa      known_hosts      ssh_config
config           id_rsa.pub  known_hosts.old  ssh_config_orig
pg@TREX:~$ 
pg@TREX:~$ ssh-copy-id -i .ssh/id_rsa 192.168.1.202
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: Source of key(s) to be installed: ".ssh/id_rsa.pub"
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: attempting to log in with the new key(s), to filter out any that are already installed
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: 1 key(s) remain to be installed -- if you are prompted now it is to install the new keys
pg@192.168.1.202's password: 

Number of key(s) added: 1

Now try logging into the machine, with:   "ssh '192.168.1.202'"
and check to make sure that only the key(s) you wanted were added.

pg@TREX:~$ ssh 192.168.1.202
Linux MediaRasPi 6.1.19-v8+ #1637 SMP PREEMPT Tue Mar 14 11:11:47 GMT 2023 aarch64

The programs included with the Debian GNU/Linux system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent
permitted by applicable law.
Last login: Wed Apr  5 09:14:01 2023 from 192.168.1.222

Wi-Fi is currently blocked by rfkill.
Use raspi-config to set the country before use.

pg@MediaRasPi:~ $
```